# Cypress MOCK api response for different status

Tags: cypress

I am testing my login component with Cypress (just started with it) and I want to handle three different cases where the API returns status 200, 400 or 500. I want to mock these responses to see how the frontend responds to that.

I want to mock the response for three different cases (200, 400 and 500) when sending a request to my API endpoint http://localhost:9999/api/login

I have written some code based on the docs but I still am not where I want to be.

```js
describe('Login Approach', () => {
  it('login', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
 // these values email and pw shouldn't matter if mocking is done right
    cy.get('#email')
      .type('test')
      .should('have.value', 'test')

    cy.get('#password')
      .type('123456')
      .should('have.value', '123456')
    cy.server()
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:9999/api/login', // this is the api that I send the request to 
    })
    cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 10000 }).should('eq', '/login');
    cy.title().should('include', 'Condeo')
    cy.get('#notification').should('exist')
  })
})
```

I am not getting status in the details of the test:

```
Method  Url                               Stubbed     Alias  #
POST    http://localhost:9999/api/login   Yes                -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `wait` method of cypress.

You can find the cypress documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Wait-for-a-specific-XHR-to-respond).

For your use case, make sure you start the server and define the route before you visit the link. Just after visiting the link, use the `cy.wait()` method which will wait for that API call to finish.

Eg.

```js
describe('Login Approach', () => {
  it('login', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
 // these values email and pw shouldn't matter if mocking is done right
    cy.get('#email')
      .type('test')
      .should('have.value', 'test')

    cy.get('#password')
      .type('123456')
      .should('have.value', '123456')
    cy.server()

    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:9999/api/login', // this is the api that I send the request to 
    }).as('login') 

    cy.location('pathname', { timeout: 10000 }).should('eq', '/login');
    cy.title().should('include', 'Condeo')
    cy.get('#notification').should('exist')
    
    // Code which will try to visit the login API. 
    cy.wait('@login').then((xhr)=> {
       if(xhr.status === 200) {
           // Code to test when status is 200
       } else if(xhr.status === 400) {
           // Code to test when status is 400
       } else {
           // Code to test when status is none of the above.
       }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, I am getting "cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: login. No request ever occurred."

Comment: Yes, you'll have to visit the URL. Either from the page or using cypress requests. Also, cypress does not support fetch API by default. It only supports XHR requests. 
So if your page uses fetch API, set `experimentalFetchPolyfill` to `true` in `cypress.json`

Comment: Thanks, I added that prop to `cypress.json`. Where can I find more details in docs about visiting the URL?

Comment: If you want to request from cypress, then  [cy.request()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Options).
Or you will have to submit the form from the page (There should be some button which you can click).